# How to tackle day light saving issue in R and get correct local time [example given]?

Tags: r, lubridate

For example London, UK follows GMT and British Summer Time (BST) .I want to extract local time from UTC timestamps .

There are 2 ways of doing it

1) Use GMT time zone for some period & BST time zone for rest.

2) Use Europe/London time for all period , would get right time considering day light savings effect .

```
df<-data.frame(utc_timestamps=c("2019-01-23 14:05:23","2019-10-23 14:05:23"),time_zone1="Europe/London",time_zone2="Etc/GMT-1")
df$utc_timestamps<-as.POSIXct(df$utc_timestamps,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")



df$local_time1<-format(df$utc_timestamps,usetz=TRUE, tz="Europe/London")
df$local_time2<-format(df$utc_timestamps,usetz=TRUE, tz="Etc/GMT-1")


utc_timestamps    time_zone1 time_zone2             local_time1             local_time2
2019-01-23 14:05:23 Europe/London  Etc/GMT-1 2019-01-23 14:05:23 GMT 2019-01-23 15:05:23 +01
2019-10-23 14:05:23 Europe/London  Etc/GMT-1 2019-10-23 15:05:23 BST 2019-10-23 15:05:23 +01
```

How do I get a full list of time zones like Europe/London , that does not get affected by day light savings.

Comment: Could you expand a little more on what you understand by "correct time"?
If the timestamps are stored in UTC, you could simply recode them into US Mountain Time Zone for the Sherman, Wallace, Greeley, and Hamilton counties, and into US Central Time Zone for the rest of Kansa's counties.

Comment: Added explaination